# Float function using pointers won't return memory address to main

Tags: c

I'm doing some practice in C and I'm required to use the following code and prototype:

```
prototype: float *avg3(float a, float b);

And code:

float *z;   
    z = avg3(22.1, 33.6);   
    printf("%.2f", *z);
```

I keep getting errors compiling, and if I do compile, it leads to the program not printing the correct value. How can I return the function so that it can return the proper value when it prints in main which is 27.85?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float *avg3(float a, float b);

int main()
{
    float *z;   
    z = avg3(22.1, 33.6);   
    printf("%.2f", *z);

    return 0;
}

float *avg3(float a, float b){
    float *z;
    *z = (a + b)/2;
    return z;
}
```

Comment: I am also using other headers <stdlib.h> and <math.h> which I forgot to include in the question. Still get the same error.

Comment: `float *z;` is unintialised, does not point to anything, so dereferencing is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Did you study `malloc` yet? This seems to be a practice of dynamic allocation.

Comment: You don't need any pointers here. If you remove every `*` the program should be good.

Comment: @WeatherVane The previous two exercises were using them without pointers, or for example, passing a pointer to the function so the function can change the value. But this one is as described only using the prototype and code given to get an output of 27.85, and all I need to do is write a function for it to work properly.

Comment: As mentioned you can allocate the memory. You could also use `static float z` and return a pointer to that.

Comment: Actually, if you can't free the pointer that is allocated with malloc then @WeatherVane is completely right - use a `static float z; z = (a + b)/2; return &z;`

Comment: A static is fine, as long  you document your function as thread/recursion unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options for how you might imagine avg3 might work, but only one of them actually works.

1) Your version:

```
    float *avg3(float a, float b) {
        float *z;  // z is uninitialised so it points to random memory you don't own
        *z = (a + b)/2; // assigning anything to random memory you don't own is a Bad Thing
        return z;
    }
```

2) Another version:

```
    float *avg3(float a, float b) {
        float z;
        z = (a + b)/2;
        return &z; // we return a pointer into the stack frame belonging to this function
    } // and here the stack frame memory belonging to this function is deleted
```

3) A working version:

```
    float *avg3(float a, float b) {
        float *z = malloc(sizeof(float)); // this returns memory you own
        if (z == NULL) { // but we have to check that there was some memory left
            puts("Not enough memory");
            return NULL;
        }
        *z = (a + b)/2; // we need to check if z == NULL before we try to use *z
        return z;
    }
```

Ok, so version 3 is good except:

- we need to free the memory after we don't need it any more (to be fair you don't need to do it if the program will end immediately after freeing the memory because the OS will do that for you but do it anyway because 1) it's best practise coding style 2) if you don't make it a habit then it WILL bite you when you program isn't meant to ever exist (like a web server for example)
- we might return NULL from the function so we should check that in main() or else we will end up using a NULL pointer (the same reason we checked for NULL after the malloc)

4) If the homework assignment rules mean that we can't add the free() call or NULL check to main then this version suggested by @WeatherVane in a comment saves us from having to change main:

```
    float *avg3(float a, float b) {
        static float z;
        z = (a + b)/2;
        return &z; // we return a pointer to the static variable 
    } // a static variable is automatically deallocated after main() returns
```

Ok, so version 4 is good except:

- static variables are good for singletons where the function returns the same pointer every time in a single threaded application.  But that isn't always true so you should read about singletons to understand when to use them.  Using static must be done very carefully in a multi-threaded environment.

So a full program for #3 would look like:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    float *avg3(float a, float b);

    int main() {
        float *z;   

        z = avg3(22.1, 33.6);   
        if (z == NULL) { // but we have to check that the function worked
            puts("That didn't work");
            return 1; // normally 0 = success, 1 = error
        }

        printf("%.2f", *z);  // we need to check if z == NULL before we try to use *z

        free(z); // we don't need the memory we allocated any more...

        return 0; // normally 0 = success, 1 = error
    }

    float *avg3(float a, float b) {
        float *z = malloc(sizeof(float)); // this returns memory you own

        if (z == NULL) { // but we have to check that there was some memory left
            puts("Not enough memory");
            return NULL;
        }

        *z = (a + b)/2; // we need to check if z == NULL before we try to use *z

        return z;
    }
```

So a full program for #4 would look like:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    float *avg3(float a, float b);

    int main() {
        float *z;   
        z = avg3(22.1, 33.6);   
        printf("%.2f", *z);
        return 0;
    } // z is deallocated here

    float *avg3(float a, float b) {
        static float z;
        z = (a + b)/2;
        return &z; // we return a pointer to the static variable 
    } // a static variable is automatically deallocated after main() returns
```

Look how much simpler version 4 looks.  It looks like a really good solution to the homework assignment as long as you only need to do this to one variable.  It gets completely out of hand if you start doing it in every function.  And it doesn't work well if the program is multi-threaded. In this particular case a singleton is appropriate so it works.

Comment: The chances of users documenting such functions as 'thread/recursion unsafe' are just about nil.  The effect of 'static' on multithreaded apps is likely to be a very intermittent, difficult-to-trace heizenbug, ie disastrous.  It makes me shudder when such solutions are described as 'elegant':(  Have an upboat anyway for mentioning the issue at all!

Comment: @MartinJames  That's a good point - I agree (maybe I should elaborate a bit more...).  I would never use such a thing myself because I write Java Tomcat web apps and be definition that's multi-threaded.  But for this homework assignment, where you can't modify the calling function, using static seems better than returning a pointer that main won't check for NULL.